# Can't mount samba-share: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13

Tags: debian, ubuntu, samba, cifs

I have samba-server on debian-PC and I trying to connect to there from another ubuntu-PC:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=USERNAME -o noacl -o vers=2.1 SERVER MOUNTPOINT
```

After enter password, I received error on console:

```
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

and error in log (tail -f  /var/log/kern.log):

```
[344394.751300] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I haven't any problem when connect to same share with same credentials from Windows-PC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution: I was to add read and execute permission for the samba user to **parent** of the share folder